Lower bound of the spectral gap of positive semi-definite matrices
Let $M$ be an $n \times n$ positive semi-definite, symmetric real matrix such that $|| M ||_2 = 1$ (with $||\cdot ||_2$ being the Schatten 2-norm) and $\dim \ker M = k < n$. Let the spectrum of $M$, consisting of non-negative real eigenvalues, be $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \ldots \ge \lambda_n$. The eigenvalues of $M$ from $\lambda_{n-k}$ to $\lambda_n$ are zero.
According to the min-max theorem, it holds that the smallest non-zero eigenvalue is given by
$$\lambda_{n-k-1} = \max_{V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n, \dim(V) = n-k-1} \min_{v \in V, \|v\|_2 = 1} v^\top M v$$
Can we derive a non-zero lower bound for $\lambda_{n-k-1}$, i.e., $\lambda_{n-k-1} \in \Omega(1/n^\alpha)$ or $\lambda_{n-k-1} \in \Omega(1/\exp(n))$, even with so little structure?
